# Effect a code change without restarting with Django and PTVS

Tags: django, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

In Django, code changes are immediately applied without restart of the web-server. This is really convenient specially to tune look and feel. To get debug support, I started using VS2013 with PTVS extension which support Django for my project. The only issue I face with this setup is after a code change it requires restart of the debug session. Is there a way to avoid this?
Before moving to VS2013, I used PyCharm and it allowed me to do this without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do it removing  --noreload from the script arguments. I hope it helps